# Why do Property Setters get called more often than expected?

Tags: vb.net, properties, getter-setter

I have observed a behaviour in VB.net where property setters get called more often than seems necessary, in conjunction with calls to the sister setter method.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Console.WriteLine("Calling WorkReferenceTypeByReference")
        WorkReferenceTypeByReference(ReferenceTypeData)
        Console.WriteLine("Called WorkReferenceTypeByReference")
        Console.WriteLine("Calling WorkReferenceTypeByValue")
        WorkReferenceTypeByValue(ReferenceTypeData)
        Console.WriteLine("Called WorkReferenceTypeByValue")
    End Sub

    Public Sub WorkReferenceTypeByReference(ByRef ref As Point)
        Dim b As Point = New Point(4, 4) + ref
        Console.WriteLine("    adding (4,4) to " & ref.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WorkReferenceTypeByValue(ByVal ref As Point)
        Dim b As Point = New Point(4, 4) + ref
        Console.WriteLine("    adding (4,4) to " & ref.ToString)
    End Sub

    Private m_ReferenceType As Point = New Point(0, 0)
    Public Property ReferenceTypeData As Point
        Get
            Console.WriteLine("  Calling ReferenceTypeData getter")
            Console.WriteLine("  returning: " & m_ReferenceType.ToString)
            Return m_ReferenceType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Point)
            Console.WriteLine("  Calling ReferenceTypeData setter")
            Console.WriteLine("  value = " & value.ToString)
            m_ReferenceType = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The previous code returns to the console the following output

```
Calling WorkReferenceTypeByReference
  Calling ReferenceTypeData getter
  returning: {X=0,Y=0}
    adding (4,4) to {X=0,Y=0}
  Calling ReferenceTypeData setter
  value = {X=0,Y=0}
Called WorkReferenceTypeByReference
Calling WorkReferenceTypeByValue
  Calling ReferenceTypeData getter
  returning: {X=0,Y=0}
  adding (4,4) to {X=0,Y=0}
Called WorkReferenceTypeByValue
```

Note the spurious call to the property setter following the method execution. I am supposing this behaviour is produced as a safety measure against inadvertently modifying the underlying property, despite this potentially being the intent.

This behaviour in the case of ByRef vs ByVal usage is easily solved by choosing appropriate ByVal keyword, however hase recently noticed a more insidious behaviour, one that has caused a stack overflow of repeated calls, since the setter call would update a value that called the getter only.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim a As New CustomObject(anotherObject.AProperty(getterArgument))
End Sub

Public Class AnotherObject

    Public Property AProperty as SomeType
        Get
            ' Get value
        End Get
        Set
            ' Set value, call DoSomething
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

In the previous example, calling DoSomething() would fire the AProperty getter method, but then after that usage, would fire the setter method, which by program logic calls DoSomething() again. It is the automatic calling of the setter that puzzles me.

Comment: Compile this code with Option Strict On to see the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is, in fact, a feature of VB.Net.  In your code, you are passing a property, not a variable, by reference.  Strictly speaking, passing a property ByRef is not possible, because ByRef needs a reference to a variable.  However, the compiler automatically creates a temporary local on your behalf and passes it to the method for you.  Because the method may change the ByRef parameter, which is now the compiler-generated temporary and not your property, the compiler then inserts a call to the setter.  Essentially, something like this happens:

```
Dim temp = Me.ReferenceTypeData
Me.WorkReferenceTypeByReference(temp)
Me.ReferenceTypeData = temp
```

Other languages, such as C#, do not allow passing a property by reference (rightly so from the strict definition of parameter passing) and instead require you to write the equivalent of the above code yourself.

Comment: Understandably passing the result of a getter by reference to a method is vague,  I guess it is just annoying that after 'finishing' with the property that got passed by reference, it feels the need to run the setter, even if no assignment is ever made to the temporary value. Is there some way to switch that off in the compiler or force the getter to generate a new value/object to pass by reference, rather than the property itself?

Comment: @JCollins The problem is that the compiler does not know if an assignment was made. (Reliably determining if an assignment or modification was made would be excessively difficult to do, so I don't expect them to try.) If you *know* the method will not make any modifications, either make the temporary yourself and don't call the setter, or change the method to ByVal if applicable. I do not believe there is a way to make the compiler change its generated code or throw an error if you pass a property ByRef.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I suppose I had simplified 'make an assignment' to a routine that directly has the value on the left of an assignment operator. Though it is possible any called subroutine might make the change, in which case I can see the difficulty.

Comment: Wow. This answered what has been plaguing me for the last hour. When I got down to the weird setter call, that's when I knew something was wrong with more than just our code. Glad I searched before wasting more time trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a VB.net "feature". You won't see this in C#. VB.NET will copy an object (in this case, a pointer) twice when you use ByRef.
See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/bc54294f-785a-467b-96ec-12d0387074e9/

"As far as I understand VB.NET, ByRef copies a parameter value twice: once when entering the method and once when returning from the method. "

So, at the end of method execution, it is basically copying itself, causing the setter to be called.

That said, there is really no point in using ByRef with any object, it's just passing the pointer anyway when you use ByVal so the effect of being able to modify the object is the same. ByRef is only useful for value types.

Comment: In this particular case the ByRef was on a value type (Double) and had some intent. Since the code logic has changed to no longer require the ByRef, I have changed it. I have grasped that ByRef on reference types actually moves a pointer to a pointer to the original value, but I'm not sure I fully understand your response on copying. It would seem that the setter should still only be called when an assignment is made to the passed-by-reference argument, which would be the sensible 'feature' of passing a property by reference.